# force float:left on divs without "white-space:nowrap"

Tags: css, css-float, nowrap

have something like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="floating">
      
      <img src="image" alt="">
      
      <p>
          text...
      </p>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="floating">
      
      <img src="image" alt="">
      
      <p>
          text...
      </p>

    </div>
    
</div>
```

I would like the "floating" divs to float on the left side of each other even though they are overflowing their container.

I tried just using "float:left" on the floating divs, but it doesn't work. They stack on each other.

So, I have found a workaround using "display:inline-block" on the floating elements and "white-space:nowrap" on the container and it works but it doesn't help in my case.

```
.container{
    width:600px; 
    border:2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap; /* delete this and see the actual floating divs layout*/
}

.floating{
    width:66%;
    display: inline-block;
}

img{
  width:120px; 
  height:120px;
  float:left;
}
```

Indeed, the "white-space:nowrap" prevents my texts to wrap around the imgs in my floating divs, which is the initial intent.
The "white-space:nowrap" does what it should do so this trick only seems to work when one doesn't care about wrapping the content inside the div. But I do in this case.

So, all in all, if I keep the white-space property, my 2 divs float as they should but the content inside them is messed up. And if I don't use the property, the content inside the divs is preserved but the divs don't float.

https://jsfiddle.net/8n0um9kz/

Is there any solution that gets me what I want ?

Thanks.

PS: I used a width of 66% for both the floating divs in the example just so that you could see both at once for illustration. In my case they are 100% each of course.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it like this.

```
.container{
    width:600px; 
    display:flex;  //required
    align-items: flex-start; //optional
    overflow:hidden;
}

.floating{
    min-width: 66%; //required
}

img{
  width:120px; 
  height:120px;
  float:left;
}
```

The key aspect was to use 'min-width' instead of 'width' and 'display:flex' on the container.

No need to use block display, remove float, justify content or wrap/unwrap anything.

'align-items: flex-start' is only required if the floating divs should keep their respective height, otherwise they will take the height of the tallest div. Which isn't a problem, unless you use background colors for your floating divs that are different from the container's.

https://jsfiddle.net/b83rzL07/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes. you have a solution.

Instead of using 'white-space : no-wrap' on the container you can use **'display : flex'**  and '**flex-wrap : wrap '**  on the container to allow the items to the next line when they come end of the container. further use '**justify-content : flex -start'**

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you give me an example please? I just used  'display : flex' and 'flex-wrap : wrap ' instead of 'white-space : nowrap'  on the container. It didn't change the problem (the content is well displayed but the divs are not floating.  And when adding 'justify-content : flex-start' on either the container or the floating divs, nothing changes. Thanks. The content is alright again but the floating isn't there.

Comment: to float content remove 'float : left' and add 'display : block'

Comment: Thanks. But I have no float:left (except on the img). An example would go a long way since I don't know what shouldn't be floated anymore and where to put the  'justify-content : flex-start' .
I believe I tried any combination I could think of that seems to be in agreement with your advice but so far, with no success.
What should I add/remove, exactly, in my jsfiddle, so that it works? I understand you don't want to serve me the answer on a plate but I just tried everything I could think of that complies with what you said, with no good outcome.

Comment: I definitely tried all possibilities according to what you said. Several times. It doesn't work. Since you seem positive, more details are necessary for me to achieve success. Thanks.